# How is Ubuntu "64-bit ARM" offered for Pi 2?

Tags: pi-2, ubuntu, 64-bit

Canonical offers [Ubuntu for "64-bit ARM"](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/22.04/release/) and gives "Pi 2" as an example of a compatible platform. Raspberrypi.com says [the Pi 2 is "32 bit"](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-os-64-bit/).

How does that work?

Comment: Let me [Google that](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=can+ARM+processor+handle+32+bit+and+64+bit&atb=v278-1&ia=web) for you. [Also - this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125314/286615) may provide some insight.

Comment: @Milliways "Raspberry Pi 2: Architecture width: 32 bit" — do you count that as "no such thing"?

Comment: @Seamus "can arm processor handle 32 bit and 64 bit" — That's one fantastic search query right there. It didn't really come any closer to answering the question though.

Comment: @Milliways It literally lists the "Products" and its "Processors", but when we come to the column called "Architecture width" suddenly the table has nothing to do with hardware? Ok.

Answer (score 1):

The best explanation I can come up with is that the Pi 2 came with two different processors, as stumbled upon in a comment to the linked article:

> Don’t forget that the later Raspberry Pi 2 (v1.2) uses the same CPU as the Raspberry Pi 3, only slightly downclocked. There’s no reason the Pi 2 v1.2 shouldn’t be able to run the 64 bit version

If anyone insists that the original BCM2836 could also run 64 bit OSes I would be happy to read an explanation, since everywhere I look it's simply [referred to as "32-bit"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-A7). If so then I'm obviously not very good at navigating the landscape of ARM terminology.